# How to send long string via Socket C#

Tags: c#

I have an issue that I convert an Image to a base64 string. Then I send that string from Server to Client. Client will Convert base64 string to an Image. But when I send, there is an error message: "The string too long to send". I count bytes that string and it is 914,813 bytes!!! How can I minimize long string? or How can I send a long string like that? Thank you.

Comment: You can use NetworkStream to read/write BLOBs.

Comment: *What* is raising this error message? And what is the nature of the sockets you're working with? I.e. most people mean TCP when they say sockets, but TCP shouldn't have any limitations like this since its abstraction is an endless stream of bytes. I could see some kind of error coming if you're using UDP sockets, but it's worth being clear in your question what you mean.

Comment: I use TCP socket, the error message is "Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization." It happens when I send a long message, maybe 180.000 chars